# Azure OS disk encryption on VM creation

Tags: java, azure, encryption, azure-virtual-machine

I want to have a virtual machine with an encrypted OS disk.

There is an [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/encrypt-disks) of how to do it in two steps: create a new virtual machine and run OS disk encryption after it.

Is it possible to create a new virtual machine with an already encrypted OS disk?

It doesn't matter what tool to use: Azure CLI, PowerShell or and programming language SDK, but Azure Java SDK is preferred.

Comment: It seems it's possible to do that, but I'm not sure. You can take a try to follow the steps in [Encryption workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-disk-encryption-overview#encryption-workflow).

Answer (score 0):

according to [Encryption scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-disk-encryption-overview#encryption-scenarios) it should be possible to create a vm with encryption:

- Enable encryption on new Windows IaaS VMs created from pre-encrypted VHD and encryption keys.
- Enable encryption on new IaaS VMs created from the supported Azure Gallery images.

I think for that to work you'd need to use [DiskEncryptionSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/createorupdate#diskencryptionsettings) while provisioning the VM

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no documentation of how to create `DiskEncryptionSetting` object for correct encryption. I tried to create it using JavaDocs and `withOSDiskEncryptionSettings` builder method, but in the result, my VM is not encrypted even though it created without errors.
I was thinking, that it must be another way, which I could take as an example and apply it to my Java code.

Comment: i suppose it would be more or less the same as this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-create-encrypted-managed-disk/CreateEncryptedManagedDisk-kek.json#L68

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible because Azure Disk Encryption can only be enabled once a VM's OS is up and running. This is because ADE leverages BitLocker which needs to be running before encryption on a disk can occur.